# How to combine this two sensor code

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I have a problem. I don’t know how to combine this two codes & the diagram. My project is about automatic water storage door that using water sensor & rain sensor. The rain sensor will function when rain while the water sensor will control the open/close door. The door will open when it rain but it will remain close when the volume in the water storage is full.the volume of water in tank was controlled by flood sensor(water sensor). Here is the code for two sensor.

rain sensor
const int senmin = 0;
const int senmax = 1024;
int led = 13;
int sensory = A0;
int i;
void setup() {
Serial.begin (9600);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
int sensor = analogRead(sensory);
int range = map(sensor, senmin, senmax, 0, 3);

switch (range)
{
case 0:
Serial.println("raining");
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

```
  break;

case 1:
  Serial.println("not raining");
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
```

}
delay(500);

}

water sensor

const int waterSens = A0; //define water sensor
const int led = 9;//define led to pin 9
int waterVal; //define the water sensor value

void setup() {
pinMode(led, OUTPUT); //set led as an output
pinMode(waterSens, INPUT);//set water sensor as an input
Serial.begin(9600);  //start the serial port at 9600 bauds

}

void loop() {
waterVal = analogRead(waterSens); //read the water sensor

Serial.println(waterVal); //print the value of the water sensor to the serial monitor

if (waterVal <= 0){
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);//if the water sensor senses water turn the led on
}
else{
digitalWrite(led, LOW);//if it doesn't sense anything turn the led off
}
}